# Line segment to arc?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, convert, line

I have a polygon shapefile in ArcMap 10 made up of several vertices/line segments. I need to convert some but not all of the sides of this polygon into arcs. Is there a way to do that without having to redraw the shape? I don't have many other programs available so I'm looking to avoid having to outsource or export the shapefile to another program.

For reference: I also work in AutoCAD 2014 and something like the "convert line to arc" command found in that program would be useful. I'm just not sure if a similar one exists in ArcMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will start an edit session, then double click on the line you want to change to an arc (so that now you are looking that vertices of the line)  In the segment (between the vertices) you want to change to arc right click here and you will see a sub menu called CHANGE SEGMENT,  choose circular arc from this selection.  Then drag your arc to the dimensions you wish.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @user3338179 thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for!